# FATAL: database "dbname" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I drop one database from production primary server. Still I'm getting error in postgresql error log on secondary server.

FATAL: database "dbname" does not exist
User: postgres

I checked, this DB is not  used from our any application or monitoring tools. This error occurred 192 times in 1 hour. That means the request comes to this DB every 3.2 sec. Any idea how to get from where this request comes ?

Comment: Some application in your environment is trying to connect to that database. Without seeing all your applications and their code this is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `log_line_prefix` parameter to contain `%h`, then the IP address of the client that tried to connect will be logged.

Comment: Ok. Can we change this setting value  on only one secondary server in pgconfig file?

Comment: Thanks. It helped me to find from where the request comes.

Comment: It is showing that the request comes from local. 2021-01-22 13:22:18.164 CET [22342] postgres@dbname,[local] FATAL:  database "dbname" does not exist                                                                            Strange is we do not have any service or tool running locally  using "postgres" user.

Comment: Some further ideas. Create a new empty `dbname` and see what the client tries to do after connecting. Add `%a` to `log_line_prefix` on chance client is sending an application name.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I tried to add %a also. I found application name is unknown.                                                                         
2021-01-25 05:21:17.691 CET [22512] postgres@DBNAME[local] [unknown] FATAL:  database "DBNAME" does not exist

Comment: From here on you are on your own. You'll have to find the offending program on your own computer. Perhaps look at all the `cron` jobs.

Comment: Is this issue because of environment variable PGDATABASE? how to check current value for PGDATABASE on postgresql ?